# SAXParseException; systemId: cumulative size of entities exceeds bound

Tags: java, xml, apache, saxparser, saxparseexception

Morning,

I have to parse a huge xml file (2GB) in **Java**. It has many tags but I only need to write the content of two tags `<title>` and `<subtext>` each time in a common file, so I use **SaxParse**

So far, I have managed to write 1M95 text in the output file, by then **this exception occurs**:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: filePath; lineNumber: x; columnNumber: y; JAXP00010004 : La taille cumulée des entités est "50 000 001" et dépasse la limite de "50 000 000" définie par "FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1465)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.checkEntityLimit(XMLScanner.java:1544)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.handleCharacter(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1940)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEntityReference(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1866)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3058)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:504)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:328)
    at Parsing.main(Class.java:38)
```

**The translation of the exception** is like:

```
The cumulative size of the entities is "50 000 001" which exceeds the boundary of "50 000 000" defined by "FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING".
```

### This is the code I've written:

```
public class Parsing {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {

    try {
        File inputFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/input.xml");
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
        UserHandler userhandler = new UserHandler();
        saxParser.parse(inputFile, userhandler);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static void doThingOne(String text, String title) throws IOException {

    // Write the text and the title on a file
}


public static void doThingTwo(String text, String title) throws IOException {
    //Write the text and the title on another file

}

class UserHandler extends DefaultHandler {

boolean bText = false;
boolean bTitle = false;
StringBuffer tagTextBuffer; 
StringBuffer tagTitleBuffer; 
String text = null;
String title = null;

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

    if (qName.equals("title")) {
        tagTitleBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        bTitle = true;
    } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("text")) {
        tagTextBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        bText = true;
    }
}

public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
    if (qName.equals("title")) {
        bTitle = false;
        title = tagTextBuffer.toString();

    } else if (qName.equals("text")) {
        text = tagTextBuffer.toString();
        bText = false;
        if (text!=null && title == "One") {
            try {
                Parsing.doThingOne(page, title);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (text != null) {
            try {
                Parsing.doThingTwo(page, title);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {
    if (bTitle) {
        tagTitleBuffer.append(new String(ch, start, length));
    } else if (bText) {
        tagTextBuffer.append(new String(ch, start, length));
    }
}
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The limit is there to prevent the "billion laughs" attack. If you trust the XML source you could switch off the SECURE_PROCESSING feature which imposes this limit.
2. I would generally recommend using Apache Xerces in preference to the version bundled with the JDK.
3. Your code for the characters() method is wrong: both the `text` and the `title` element content can be delivered split into multiple calls so you need to accumulate a buffer for both cases.
4. It would be nice to know something about why the entity expansion limit is being hit. Does your document include lots of entity references to tiny entities, or a few references to big ones, or what? Do the entity references occur in the parts of the document you are interested in?

Comment: Thank you for your answer
1) I guess so, it was provided by my teacher. 
2) Do I have to download if from [here] ? (http://xerces.apache.org/mirrors.cgi)
3) Okay I have edited this.
4) a. I The file is very huge so I can only read it with the Terminal. Are they displayed in the terminal?

Answer (score 1):

Switch off the *FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING* has no effect (Java8).
For increases the limit, use :

```
System.setProperty("jdk.xml.totalEntitySizeLimit", String.valueOf(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
```

before SAXParserFactory.newInstance();